# what is the use of --print-defaults in mysql

Tags: mysql

what is the use of --print-defaults in mysql. 
what are the advantages and disadvantages.
can we add it in my.cnf file

Regards,
Chinta kiran

Answer (score 0):

Print the program name and all options that it gets from option files.

Comment: can you eloborate it more. here are the few snap shots. mysql --print-defaults
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=kiran --password=kiran@123

 mysql --no-defaults
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[root@vishnuvm5 kiran.chinta]#

Comment: the error you get is because of the way try to set the pass - try this: 

mysql --print-defaults -u kiran -pkiran@123 mysql --no-defaults